# React and Axios: how to handle the error 422 with message 'The status field must be true or false.' when submitting a checked checkbox

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm learning how to use react and Axios and I've created a form that has one checkbox named "status" in it. When I check said checkbox and click on the Submit button, I get the error *422 (Unprocessable Content)* on the Console, with a message on the Network Preview that says *"The status field must be true or false."*
When I leave it unchecked it works fine, as I have set the "status" as false by default, but when it's checked its value becomes a string ("on").

This is the code I used:

```
const [survey, setSurvey] = useState({
        title: "",
        slug: "",
        status: false,
        description: "",
        image: null,
        image_url: null,
        expire_date: "",
        questions: []
    });

const onSubmit = (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();

        const payload = {...survey};

        if(payload.image){
            payload.image = payload.image_url;
            delete payload.image_url
        }

        axiosClient.post('/surveys', payload).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })


    }
```

The code for the checkbox input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status" id="status" checked={survey.status} onChange={(ev) => setSurvey({...survey, status: ev.target.value})} className="h-4 w-4 rounded border-gray-300 text-indigo-600 focus:ring-indigo-500"/>
```

Comment: "*The status field must be true or false*" + "*but when it's checked its value becomes a string ("on")*" = you have the answer right here; make it `true` when it's checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the default value for a checkbox is "on" as you can see in [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#value)

If you want it to be true, you should either check the value in the onchange attribute or set the value property to true.